# Vscode intelephense highlighting all Woocommerce functions and throwing Undefined function 'woocommerce_SomeFunction

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm currently developing a small WordPress theme project using Visual Studio Code (VSCode) as my code editor with the Intelephense extension for code completion. Initially, I faced a similar issue where vscode was highliting all WordPress functions and hooks in red, even though there were no PHP errors and the website was running perfectly fine. I managed to solve the issue it by adding 'WordPress' to the Stubs list in the Intelephense configuration.

Now, I've added WooCommerce support to my theme, but I'm encountering the same problem with WooCommerce functions and hooks being highlighted in red. However, this time, I couldn't find 'WooCommerce' in the Stubs list to resolve the issue. Even though the website still functions correctly, this highlighting is causing confusion while working on the theme.

Has anyone encountered a similar issue with Woocommerce and the Intelephense extension in VSCode ? Any guidance on how to resolve this issue and get accurate code highlighting for WooCommerce functions in VSCode would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For now i guess i will be disabling the vscode intelephense feature maybe it's just not supported.

Comment: The WooCommerce [VS Code Extension from Claudio Sanches](https://github.com/claudiosanches/vscode-woocommerce) has not been updated since 5/6 years, but just very few methods are not recognized, like for WC_Order_Item_Product (order line item) the method get_product_id().

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you very much for the information I will search and install this Claudio Sanches extension right now, I am sure that it will be useful.

Answer (score 2):

For the Intelephense extension to find the functions definitions you need a local wordpress installation with woocommerce and include the absolute paths in the extensions settings.

An example of configuration in a windows system using the *.vscode\settings.json* file:

```
{
   "intelephense.enviroment.includePaths": [
      "C:\\Webs\\Wordpress\\wp6_site\\wp-includes",
      "C:\\Webs\\Wordpress\\wp6_site\\wp-content\\plugins\\woocommerce\\includes"
   ]
}
```

Comment: That's some useful information to know so you have some additional config to do in the extension settings!!. Well, I will try this up another time.